# ASP.NET Core 6 configuration - different databases on different enviroments

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-6.0

I wanted to achieve different database connections with different configurations (i.e. Test for testing and Demo for production) but got stuck real hard.

I really don't know how to make a configuration file, let alone make a dependency of connection. I have one though, for the test purposes, and its working, but i don't know how to change it with environment

Comment: show code.. to see how you are making the SQL connection

Comment: Its using connection string within the code

Comment: What code? we aren't mind readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exactly why they have launchsettings.json.
You can setup environment variables with connection strings for each enviornmet that you need.
See following link for examples:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#lsj

Answer (score 1):

You can add different appsettings.json file.
in production the connection string will be read from this file.

[image: appsettings.json]

and in development you can have appsettings.development.json

[image: appsettings.development.json]

In development the connection string will be used from this file.