# Different databases depending on configuration c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

[ASP.NET Core 6 configuration - different databases on different enviroments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72690782/asp-net-core-6-configuration-different-databases-on-different-enviroments) < There was an answer for enviroments. Now I faced same problem, but today I need to make different connection strings with different configurations. All conn.strings are stored in App.config file and i can't seem to change it no matter how hard I tried. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754871/3181933

Comment: This question only seems different to the last if you mean you have (for example) three "Development" configurations, etc. but even then you can just set the environment in each configuration, so the previous answer still holds.